I followed the tutorial to create a Spring Cloud OAuth2 single sign-on project. Why did I fail to access the interface?
I want to access the client interface that needs to log in. First, I set the Authorization Type to OAuth2 in postman, enter the relevant information to obtain the access token, click Get New Access Token. Then jump to the login page. After logging in, I use the token I obtained to access the interface. As a result, the resources corresponding to the interface are not returned, but redirected to the login page. Why does this result occur? Is there an error in the code? How to change it?
get new access token  ，fail to access interface， the code structure of the authentication server
Part of the authentication server code：
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("jwtTokenStore")
    private TokenStore tokenStore;
    @Autowired
    private JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter;
    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenEnhancer jwtTokenEnhancer;

    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        TokenEnhancerChain enhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        List<TokenEnhancer> delegates = new ArrayList<>();
        delegates.add(jwtTokenEnhancer);
        delegates.add(jwtAccessTokenConverter);
        enhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(delegates);
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                 .userDetailsService(userService)
                 .tokenStore(tokenStore)
                 .accessTokenConverter(jwtAccessTokenConverter)
                .tokenEnhancer(enhancerChain);
    }

    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("admin")
                .secret(passwordEncoder.encode("admin123456"))
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(3600)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(864000)
                .redirectUris("http://localhost:9501/login")
                .autoApprove(true)
                .scopes("all")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "password", "refresh_token");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) {
        security.tokenKeyAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }
}


the code structure of the client
Part of the client code：
server:
  port: 9501
  servlet:
    session:
      cookie:
        name: OAUTH2-CLIENT-SESSIONID
oauth2-server-url: http://localhost:9401
spring:
  application:
    name: oauth2-client
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      client-id: admin
      client-secret: admin123456
      user-authorization-uri: ${oauth2-server-url}/oauth/authorize
      access-token-uri: ${oauth2-server-url}/oauth/token
    resource:
      jwt:
        key-uri: ${oauth2-server-url}/oauth/token_key


Complete code：https://github.com/Bernalette/oauth2-test
